# Yes/No instead of OK Cancel

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have `MFC` dialog form with `OK/Cancel` buttons. After pressing these buttons form is closed and I have modal result `IDOK/IDCANCE`L. Now I would like to have buttons that would close form in the same way and return `IDYES/IDNO` in modal result. How to do that?

Comment: Call **[`EndDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wddd3ztw.aspx)** when button is pressed.

Comment: You can always overrode [`DoModal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/619z63f5.aspx) and translate `IDOK`/`IDCANCEL` to `IDYES`/`IDNO`.

Comment: On button click I have added code ::EndDialog( this->m_hWnd,IDYES); Window closes, but code does not returns from doModal()

Comment: Don't use global `::EndDialog`. Use appropriate member of `CDialog`: `EndDialog(IDYES)`.

Answer (score 3):

A dialog provides OnOk() and OnCancel() functionality but not OnYes() or OnNo(). You simply add buttons to implement that yourself and since IDYES and IDNO are defined by MFC you can just call the following:

```
EndDialog( IDYES ); // when yes is pressed

EndDialog( IDNO ); // when no is pressed
```